# Making One FORM from two Tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle APEX. i want to make one `form i-e A` from two tables `B & C` .When i enter data in `form A`  the data from `form`A should go to their respective Tables `B & C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view and if necessary an INSTEAD OF trigger?

Creat a view of the data from tables B and C.  Base your form on this.  When you do your insert/update of the data you can either do so against the view (if its simple enough) or use an INSTEAD OF trigger to trap the update/insert and run the trigger.  Google INSTEAD OF triggers.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer, unless you are planning on elaborating on this further.

Comment: @Karl Can you elaborate the trigger for Table B & C having 4 dummy attributes for each table